# Facebook API - how get ad accounts id

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token, facebook-ads-api

I'm using Facebook graph API v2.9, and in login use scope:

> email,ads_management,ads_read,business_management,pages_show_list,user_managed_groups,user_events,read_insights

I created an application on developers.facebook.com.br and associated the Marketing API, where I have only myself as an administrator.

When I log in to the application that I am developing with my facebook account I succeed, however if someone else tries to use my tool with this person's facebook login, when trying to call api

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v3.0/me/adaccounts?fields=name,account_id,account_status,id&access_token={TOKEN_LOGIN}
```

> {
>      "error": {
>         "message": "(#3) Application does not have the capability to make this API call.",
>         "type": "OAuthException",
>         "code": 3,
>         "fbtrace_id": "DAoQR9tEODK"
>      }
>   }

gives the following error:

My question is if someone else uses this API, will I have to add it as an application manager, or if is there another fetch to get all adaccount_id without that person being a member of my application?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/access#faqs: _“For development and basic access apps, configure a list of ad accounts your app is able to make API calls for in an Account List.”_ - did you do that?

Comment: Yes, but i want access in other adaccount that I don't have access..

Comment: Then you would have to apply for Standard access level first.